# Visualizing a Boxplot in R from a csv file

Tags: r, csv, markdown, boxplot

I want to visualize some imported data from a csv file in a Boxplot using R.

I made it when the data is not imported (but given in code). Otherwise when I try to read it from the csv, I got wrong data in plot as shown in this screenshot:
[image: wrong boxplot]

Actually, the data should be shown in this way:
[image: Correct Boxplot]

And this the code that I've tried:

t-test:

```
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- read.csv2(file="C:\\Users\\alex\\data.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE)
data[data == 'NA_integer_'] <- NA
t.test(data$NF, data$F)

df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    

                           
                           
results <- t.test(data$`non-failing heart (NF)`, data$`failing heart (F)`)


                           
results$statistic
results$estimate
results$p.value
```

Boxplot:

```
df$NF <- df$`non-failing heart (NF)`
df$F <- df$`failing heart (F)`
boxplot(df[3:4],
        data=df,
        cex.lab=0.65,
        xlab="Fig. 1 IRE binding activity for non-failing (NF) and failing (F) hearts.",
        ylab="IRE binding activity (%)",
        col="orange",
        border="brown",
        ylim = c(0, 120)
)
```

And finally this is the screenshot from the csv file:

[image: data.csv]

Comment: Please **don't** post images of your data, but include example data by using `dput`

Comment: @starja thanks for your comment, I did it that to make it clear